# ios swift nsxmlparser - parser "drops off" parsing rss feed

Tags: ios, xml, rss, nsxmlparser

I have implemented delegate for this and can successfully parse own xml documents and rss feeds.

However, now I have stumbled across what may be a broken rss feed where the code fails horribly.

This is how it starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <atom:link href
```

Calling **p.parse()**

I in **parser(parser: NSXMLPARSER, foundCharacters string: String)** get:

*rss, newline, channel, newline*

after which the parser drops out and does not return any new tags... (Stepping seems to land me in instruction set code, not ObjC or Swift)

...

Running https://validator.w3.org against the feed gives:

*This feed does not validate*

> line 4, column 183: XML parsing error: :4:183: not
>   well-formed (invalid token) [help] ...
>   alse&cntnt01returnid=15&showtemplate=false" rel="self"
>   type="applica ...

Could this be the reason for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I just had to replace & with & in the cases where the & was not part of entity but stood alone